# I need to increase the number of letters checked in an input to find ever possible palindrome

Tags: python, palindrome

Im trying to find a way to filter through an input of letters to find the longest possible palindrome and i have found a way to look through it but only 3 letter palindromes, i need to be able to increase than number

```
#takes input
line = input("Input a word to determine if its a palindrome or not. ")
second = []
third = []
last = []

#splits input into seperate characters
def cut(line):
    return [char for char in line]
whole = cut(line)

#checks the given item "second" on weather or not it's a palindrome returns true or false
def isPalindrome(l):
    return l == l[::-1]

#backup to return "whole" to original form
third = whole

#starts by adding 3 letters to list "second" the three letters are checked if theyre a palindrome and then added to "last" and the first letter is erased so then the first 3 can be checked again, number of letters checked should go up by one after all the letters are used.
for j in range(len(whole)):
    for i in range(len(whole)):
        second = whole[:3]
        del whole[0:1]
        item =''.join(map(str,second))
#returns whole to original form
    whole = third

#if palindrome its added to final list "last"
    ans = isPalindrome(item)
    if ans == True:
        last.append(item)

print(last)
```

Comment: Do you meant to find longest possible substring from given string which is palindrome?

Comment: Yeah i have an assignment that requires me to find that

Answer (score 0):

Your code is unnecessarily complex. Try approaching the issue from the point of view that to find the longest palindrome in your word, you need to satisfy the following conditions:

Where n = number of distinct occurrences

- letters with an even number of occurrences
- letters with an odd number of occurrences using max(len(odd_occurrence))
  For example:

```
Given line = aaabbccddddd,

even_occurrences = ['bb','cc']
odd_occurrences = ['aaa','ddddd']

Hence longest possible palindrome will use 'ddddd' for the centre section 
and 'bb' & 'cc' for the side sections to end up with: 
bcdddddcb
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: I think the question is geared towards finding the longest possible palindrome-substring contained in a given string. Example: `"myracecargosbrum"` -> `"racecar"`. This doesn't seem to be solving that problem.

Answer (score 0):

I think the following code snippet might be close to what you are after.  It splits up the entered set of words into individual words, then checks for palindromes, and if found, keeps track of the longest one.

```
# Splits input into seperate characters
def cut(line):
    return [char for char in line]
   
# Takes input
line = input("Input a word to determine if its a palindrome or not. ")

words = line.split()

#print(words)

longest = 0
longestPalindrome = ""

for items in words:

    whole = cut(items)
    ans = True

    for j in range(len(whole)):
        #print(whole[j], whole[len(whole) - j - 1])
        if (whole[j] != whole[len(whole) - j - 1]):
            ans = False
            break

    if ans == True:
        print(items, " is a palindrome")
        if (len(whole) > longest):
            longest = len(whole)
            longestPalindrome = items
    else:
        print(items, " is not a palindrome")

if longest > 0:
    print("The longest palindrome found was", longestPalindrome, "at", longest, "letters long")
else:
    print("No palindromes were found")
```

The trick here is working from both ends of the word to the center of the word to see if the letters match as the comparison gets to the center of the word.

I tried this out with some short palindrome words and a long Finnish word which supposedly is the longest palindrome word at nineteen characters.

```
Input a word to determine if its a palindrome or not. What did otto say saippuakivikauppias
What  is not a palindrome
did  is a palindrome
otto  is a palindrome
say  is not a palindrome
saippuakivikauppias  is a palindrome
The longest palindrome found was saippuakivikauppias at 19 letters long
```

See if that works for you.

Regards.

Answer (score 0):

```
"""
Code is always a better description of a problem than a verbal description.
So based entirely on the input statement provided, I propose the following answer.
"""
line = input("Input a word to determine if its a palindrome or not. ")
# The original code indicates a familiarity with slicing. So the solution uses
# The 3rd part of slicing. That is the step value.
if line == line[::-1]:
    print(f'{line=} is a palindrome.')
else:
    print(f'{line=} is not a palindrome.')
```